# Can't generate release APK of new coded in React Native

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native

I'm struggling with this issue where I can't generate a APK locally with my coded changes in a React Native `0.67.2` project.

I already did run some of those commands down below to generate a new updated bundle:

`npx react-native bundle --entry-file index.js  --platform android --dev false --bundle-output ./android/app/src/main/assets/index.android.bundle --assets-dest ./android/app/src/main/res`

But everytime after running `npx react-native run-android --variant=release`, it installs an older version of my project.

If I just run it as default `npx react-native run-android`, which is as `debug` it works perfectly and install the updated version on my emulator.

It doesn't makes any sense to me, what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Try using this command to generate a new APK :

```
cd android && ./gradlew clean assembleRelease -PMYAPP_UPLOAD_STORE_PASSWORD=foo -PMYAPP_UPLOAD_KEY_PASSWORD=foo
```

And you'll find it in

yourProject/android/app/build/outputs/apk/debug/app-debug.apk

Comment: I already did this aswell, same problem